# Change a path without reloading the templateUrl content in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

is it possible to switch from route to route without reloading the template content?

Is just that I would like to keep jqGrid table data and input values among views just like ExtJS does.

this is example the code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/z90q2W?p=preview

I want to keep the input value in route1 when I go to index and go back to route1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are reloaded whenever there is a route change, losing their state. If you want to keep the input value, you'll need to pass it to a service and then retrieve it from the other controller.